# How can i remove overflow scroller border from bottom in html

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap table with overflow scroll (.table-responsive). Its working fine but i want to remove scroller from bottom. how can i remove it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:1500px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because your table is wider than it's container. Either you **remove the inline style with 1500px** or give `overflow-x: hidden;` to the container which will disable the horizontal scrolling, but your table's width will be the same and a big part of it will be invisible

If you want to keep the horizontal scrolling, but want to hide the scrollbar, then you should try this:

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
```

**NOTE: it works only in webkit based browsers**

Comment: i need horizontal scrolling but without scrollbar.

Comment: @RohitVerma Please edit your question with proper explanation of what you want rather than just downvoting answers that answered your current question on how to "remove the scrollbar". Cheers.

Comment: i want to hide scrollbar nothing else.

Comment: I updated my answer, please remove the downvotes from the answers, because they were good for your initial question

Comment: @PatrikAlexits I have upvoted your answer because it answered his initial current question mate. Cheers.

Comment: @AndrewL64 did the same with yours

Comment: Now its working fine what i need. Thanks @Patrik Alexits